# How to write Numbers With Commas?

Tags: c++, numbers

Sometimes in C++ I want to use large number like 1000000 and it's confusing. How can I use commas (if that is possible)?

For example I want this to work

```
int x = 1,000,000;
```

Comment: This is called *thousand separator*, and not all locales use comma for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You an use the [digit separator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf) since c++14

```cpp
int x = 1'000'000
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: What if I used them wrong like: int x=1'0?

Comment: @ariel • `int x=1'0;` is not using them wrong.  They are intended to be a separator for readability.  Cosmetic, like a comment.  That's an unusual grouping, but isn't wrong.